# Play / Scala / Futures: Chained Requests

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to perform what is probably a simple operation, but running into difficulties: I have a Play controller that creates a user in Mongo, but I first want to verify that there is not already a user with the same email address. I have a function on my User object that searches for a User by email address and returns a Future[Option[User]]:

```
  def findByEmail(email: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
    collection.find(Json.obj("email" -> email)).one[User]
  }
```

My controller function that searches for a User by email works:

```
  def get(id: String) = Action.async {
    User.findById(id).map {
      case None => NotFound
      case user => Ok(Json.toJson(user))
    }
  }
```

I have a function that creates a user:

```
  def create(user:User): Future[User] = {
    // Generate a new id
    val id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString

    // Create a JSON representation of the user
    val json = Json.obj(
      "id" -> id,
      "email" -> user.email,
      "password" -> user.password,
      "firstName" -> user.firstName,
      "lastName" -> user.lastName)

    // Insert it into MongoDB
    collection.insert(json).map { 
      case writeResult if writeResult.ok == true => User(Some(id), user.email, user.password, user.firstName, user.lastName)
      case writeResult => throw new Exception(writeResult.message)    
    }
  }
```

And the corresponding controller function works:

```
  def post = Action.async(parse.json) {
    implicit request =>
      request.body.validate[User].map {
        user => User.create(user).map {
          case u => Created(Json.toJson(u)) 
        }
      }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest))
  }
```

But when I modify the post method to first check for a User with the specified email it fails:

```
  def post = Action.async(parse.json) {
    implicit request =>
      request.body.validate[User].map {
        user => User.findByEmail(user.email).map {
          case None => User.create(user).map {
            case u => Created(Json.toJson(u)) 
          }
          case u => BadRequest
        }
      }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest))
  }
```

It reports that while it expects a Future[Result], it found a Future[Object]. I think the error means that it ultimately found a Future[Future[Result]], which is not what it expects.

My question is: what is the best practice for chaining such calls together? Should I add an Await.result() call to wait for the first operation to complete before proceeding? Will that cause any unwanted synchronous operations to occur? Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course `Await` will add synchronisation, which is not wanted. There error is due to heterogeneous value inside the `Future`. Make sure the return type is the same for all the cases.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your code. Looking just to this block for awhile:

```
case None => create(user).map {
    case u => Created("")
}
case u => BadRequest
```

**First**, `create(user).map { ... }` returns a `Future[Result]`, but `case u => BadRequest` returns a `Result`, then the compiler goes to a more "wide" type, which is `Object`. Let's separate this block (changes just to illustrate my point):

```
val future: Future[Object] = findByEmail("").map {
  case Some(u) => BadRequest
  case None => create(User()).map {
    case u => Created("")
  }
}
```

Now, it is clear that both case blocks must return the same type:

```
val future: Future[Future[Result]] = findByEmail("").map {
  case Some(u) => Future.successful(BadRequest)
  case None => create(User()).map {
    case u => Created("")
  }
}
```

Notice how I've changed from `case Some(u) => BadRequest` to `case Some(u) => Future.successful(BadRequest)` and now we have `Future[Future[Result]]`, which is not what we want and shows the **second problem**. Let's see the `Future.map` signature:

```
def map[S](f: T => S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```

Forget about the implicit executor, because it is irrelevant for this discussion:

```
def map[S](f: T => S): Future[S]
```

So, we receive a block that transforms from `T` to `S` and we then wrap `S` into a `Future`:

```
val futureInt: Future[Int] = Future.successful(1)
val futureString: Future[String] = futureInt.map(_.toString)
```

But what if the block returns another `Future`? Then it will be wrapped and you will get a `Future[Future[...]]`:

```
val futureFuture: Future[Future[String]] = futureInt.map(v => Future.successful(v.toString))
```

To avoid the wrap, we need to use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
val futureInt: Future[Int] = Future.successful(1)
val futureString: Future[String] = futureInt.flatMap(v => Future.successful(v.toString))
```

Let's go back to your code and use a `flatMap` instead:

```
val future: Future[Result] = findByEmail("").flatMap {
  case Some(u) => Future.successful(BadRequest)
  case None => create(User()).map {
    case u => Created("")
  }
}
```

And then, the final version will be:

```
def post = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  request.body.validate[User].map { user =>
    findByEmail(user.email) flatMap { // flatMap instead of map
      case Some(u) => Future.successful(BadRequest) // wrapping into a future
      case None => create(user).map {
        case u => Created(Json.toJson(u))
      }
    }
  }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I still do not understand completely the difference between map and flatMap, but after doing enough research and reading, I see that flatMap meets my use case perfectly. One more question for you: is there a more elegant way to solve this problem using for comprehensions? I read that for comprehensions help make flatMap() calls more readable and avoid a lot of the nesting. I'm trying to rewrite it now, but any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's a pretty good reference that is shedding light on my map vs flatMap question: [Play Framework: async I/O without the thread pool and callback hell](https://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-async-io-without-thread-pool-and-callback-hell)