# Nested async calls in controller

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework

I have an endpoint like this:

```
POST /user/:id/addData
```

And the controller function looks like this:

```
def addData(id: Int) = Action.async { implicit request =>

    // Async #1 - Make sure this user exists
    usersDAO.get(id).map(user => {
        is(user.isEmpty) {
            BadRequest("That user doesn't exist")
        } else {

            val body = request.body.asJson.get.as[JsObject]
            // Data processing here ...

            // Async #2 - Insert some data from the POST body
            (for {
                foo <- fooDAO.insert(fooData)
                bar <- barDAO.insert(barData)
            } yield (foo, bar)).map {
                case options => Ok("Data was added!")
            }.recover {  // <-------------------------- Compilation error here
                case e => BadRequest(e)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I am getting a compile time error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
 required: play.api.mvc.Result
```

---

I believe that the error is because the execution context is inside the first async call (aka one Future), so since I am entering another async call, its like I am returning nested Futures.

What is the correct way to do this?  If possible I would like to un-nest these calls (like Promises in Javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is very close to the one explained at the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35640546/4600

Basically, you are mapping a `Future` but are returning two different types inside your `map`:

```
if(user.isEmpty) {
  BadRequest("That user doesn't exist")
}
```

The `if` block above returns a `Result` and the `else` block returns a `Future[Result]`. But it was required that it returns a `Result` so that the `map` will result in a `Future[Result]` and not a `Future[Future[Result]]`.

Now, that is pretty simple to solve:

1. First, since you are using async calls (resulting in a `Future`) inside your `map`, you should not use `map`, but `flatMap` (please, see the answer linked below to more details).
2. All the blocks inside your `flatMap` must return a `Future[Result]`.

Here we go (see the comments):

```
def addData(id: Int) = Action.async { implicit request =>

  // See that we are now using a flatMap
  usersDAO.get(id).flatMap(user => {
    if(user.isEmpty) {
      // Return a future instead of a Result
      Future.successful(BadRequest("That user doesn't exist"))
    } else {

      val body = request.body.asJson.get.as[JsObject]

      // Just to be more explicity about the types and to
      // be easier to made comments below.
      val future: Future[(Foo, Bar)] = for {
        foo <- fooDAO.insert(fooData)
        bar <- barDAO.insert(barData)
      } yield (foo, bar)

      // This map returns a Future[Result] which is exactly what
      // out flatMap about expects.
      future.map {
        case options => Ok("Data was added!")
      }.recover { // This also returns a Future[Result] and now the compiler is happy
        case e => BadRequest(e)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if/else is trying to return both a `Result` and a `Future[Result]` within the outer `map`, when this `Future#map` expects a `Result`. The simplest way to make this work is to change `usersDAO.get(id).map { ...` to `usersDAO.get(id).flatMap { ...`  and wrap `BadRequest("That user doesn't exist")` within `Future.successful(...)`.

Since all of these methods seem to return futures, you can make this more elegant by putting them all in a for-comprehension:

```
def addData(id: Int) = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    (for {
        user <- usersDAO.get(id).filter(_.nonEmpty)
        body = request.body.as[JsObject]
        foo <- fooDAO.insert(fooData)
        bar <- barDAO.insert(barData)
    } yield {
        // user, body, foo, bar are in scope here
        Ok("Data was added!")
    }) recover {
        case _: NoSuchElementException => BadRequest("That user doesn't exist")
        case e => BadRequest(e)
    }
}
```

This might not compile right away, as I'm not certain what all of your return types are. Note that I also added the `BodyParser` `parse.json`, so that you can just write `request.body`.